# SSIS 2012 and SAP HANA

Tags: ssis, hana

Does anyone know if it's possible to use SSIS 2012 to import data into (or out of) SAP HANA? I've looked online and can't seem to find much about the two working together. I know that SAP Data Services is the recommended ETL tool for HANA, but we'd like to try and use SSIS if possible.

Comment: Based on this [article](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2012/09/12/and-along-came-net) it sounds like .NET can work with HANA just fine. The query itself looked like normal SQL so find the right provider and away you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found a nice article to this question. The author of the blogpost found a way to connect SSIS with SAP HANA. He used ODBC to solve this problem.

http://www.dwknight.com/sap/etl-sap-hana-microsoft-ssis/

EDIT - Link is broken - here is an archive link
https://web.archive.org/web/20150111100114/http://www.dwknight.com/sap/etl-sap-hana-microsoft-ssis