# SAP HANA ODBC Connections using SSDT/SSIS

Tags: ssis, odbc, sql-server-data-tools, hana

We are migrating our SAP BW instance from MSSQL to HANA DB and have the requirement to use SSIS out of the system.  Using SSDT(VS2010), I get a variety of errors when trying to read data from HANA.  I have the drivers installed and can connect and query the data in a small C# app I wrote (will post that code below as well).

Similar Stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943765/why-does-my-odbc-connection-fail-when-running-an-ssis-load-in-visual-studio-but): My settings are:
[image]

## First error

Using the .Net Provider for ODBC connections
[image: .NET ODBC]

I get the following error:
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.

Failed Validation? Is this an authorization issue?  No
[image: User PW]

## Second Error

Using straight ODBC connection
[image: ODBC]

I get the following errors:

> [ODBC Source [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1hVT.jpg)] Error: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager HANA_ODBC failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: ODBC Source failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.

[Connection manager "HANA_ODBC"] Error: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.

Same success on connection manager:
[image: success 1]

## Third Error

Using .NET HANA Provider supplied when you install HANA Client
[image]

I don't even see the option for the 32bit DSN.  Only the 64bit DSN shows and when user and pass is entered it throws an exception.

64bit DSN:
[image]

32bit DSN:
[image]

C# that can connect and query data from HANA:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection())
            {
                string myConnectionString;                
                myConnectionString = "DSN=HANA32;SERVERNODE=MyHana:30015;UID=SYSTEM;PWD=MyPW;DATABASENAME=DB";
                myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                }
                catch (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);               
                }
                if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Console.Write("Connection Open");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    OdbcCommand DbCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
                    DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT \"BATCH\" FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"ZBW/ZBATCH_ATTRS\" LIMIT 10";
                    OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(DbReader["BATCH"].ToString());

                    }        
                    DbReader.Close();
                    DbCommand.Dispose();
                    myConnection.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Failure");
                    Console.ReadLine();                                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Console]

Stack question here: [Hana and SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617840/ssis-2012-and-sap-hana) has an answer but the link in the answer is dead.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I found an archive.org mirror of the original link and posted it to the question you referenced.  If the link resolves your issue, I would go ahead and write up an SO self-answer so others don't run into the same issue.

Comment: The new link does not work for me

Comment: not sure what to tell you. The link works for me.  Can you get to anything on archive.org?

Comment: I can get to archive.org, but I am unable to reach your link.  I have however solved the above issue.  I will post solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this was a bad registry entry on the 32bit driver for HANA ODBC.  The correct entries should look like this:

64bit:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\HDBODBC
[image: 64bit Driver]

32bit:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SAP HANA for MS Excel
[image: 32bit Driver]